# How can I use a checkbox to modify an HREF?

Tags: javascript

I am making an image gallery with a user preference checkbox that displays a large or jumbo size image when the thumbnail is clicked. I have a form element on the page that looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="targetbox" id="pref"
    onclick="supersize(this.checked);">
<label for="pref">Supersize Pics</label>
```

I also have a link and thumbnail like this:

```
<a href="images/large/image1.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/image1.jpg" /></a>
```

The part that is giving me some trouble is the JavaScript. Here is what I was able to cobble together so far:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function supersize(checkme) {
        if (checkme)
            where = "images/super/";
        else
            where = "images/large/";

        for (var i=0; i<=(document.links.length-1); i++) {
            document.links[i].href = where;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will replace the links, but not how I need them. Obviously, this will replace the entire `href`, and I need to retain the "image1.jpg" so the new link would be something like: "images/super/image1.jpg". I am sure I need to use an array or split the url into two parts or something. That's the part I am having trouble figuring out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fyi, usually people use `i < n` instead of `i <= n-1` in their loop conditions. Using the latter will just confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a simple `replace()`:

```
var href = document.links[i].href;
if (href.indexOf('super') > -1){
    document.links[i].href = href.replace('super','large');
}
else {
    document.links[i].href = href.replace('large','super');
}
```

This will, of course, simply replace the `large` string with the `super` string, or vice versa. So, tailor your `if` to suit.

References:

- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` if you know the last value:

```
document.links[i].href = document.links[i].href.replace("last/value/goes/here/", where);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

*hrefLink.lastIndexOf('/')+1* gets the position of the last "/" and .substr() fetches the image name, which can later be appended to whatever you want !

```
<script language="JavaScript">
   function supersize(checkme) {
      if (checkme)
         where = "images/super/";
      else
         where = "images/large/";
      for (var i=0; i<=(document.links.length-1); i++) {
         hrefLink = document.links[i].href;     
         imgName =  hrefLink.substr(hrefLink.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
         document.links[i].href = where+imgName;
      }
   }
</script>
```

This way, we keep the function independent of the hard-coded words like "super" and "large" here in your context.

Cheers,
Harsha.